# How to draw / render to a widget using the widgets Xid in GTK/Cairo in 'C'

Tags: c, linux, gtk, x11, cairo

I have a need to write a `GTK` application in `C` that does some animation using `Cairo` that will render into a `GTK` widget that exists in another running application. The idea is to do the very same thing you can do with `VLC` and `Mplayer`. For example `Mplayer` has the `-wid` option:

> -wid  (also see -guiwid) (X11, OpenGL and DirectX only)
>       This tells MPlayer to attach to an existing window. Useful to embed MPlayer in a browser (e.g. the plugger extension). This option
>   fills the given window completely, thus aspect scaling, panscan, etc
>   are no longer handled by MPlayer but must be managed by the
>   application that created the window.

With this `Mplayer` option you can create a GTK application with a GTKImage widget, get it's Xid and then play a movie in the `GTK` application using `Mplayer` with the Xid specified.

I'm trying to do the same thing except render/draw into the external window using `Cairo`. Anybody have suggestions or better yet a small code sample?

Comment: I don't think you can render anything into another process's window. However, I'd be happy if rodrigo's solution works, because I'm certainly open to being wrong ;-)

Comment: I *can* be done because I've done it before. Wrote a simple GTK app that contained among other things a GtkImage widget. I was able to get the GtkImage widget Xid and pass it to Mplayer ( a separate process ) which then rendered a movie into my Gtk apps GtkImage. Here is a C++ gtkmm example of such a thing.

http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-plugs-sockets-example.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look to the `GtkSocket` and `GtkPlug` classes.

The main program will create a `GtkSocket` and the `XID` you can pass to the other program will be returned by the function `gtk_socket_get_id()`. Then the other program will use it as argument to the `gtk_plug_new()` function. All the render will be done in children of this new `GtkPlug` object.

**UPDATE**: Well, if you want... here it is a minimal example of `GtkSocket/GtkPlug`. You don't say if you are using GTK+2 or GTK+3, so I'm assuming version 2.

## server.c:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *wnd = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GtkWidget *sck = gtk_socket_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(wnd), sck);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(wnd), 400, 300);
    gtk_widget_show_all(wnd);

    GdkNativeWindow nwnd = gtk_socket_get_id(GTK_SOCKET(sck));
    g_print("%lu\n", nwnd);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

## client.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <cairo/cairo.h>
#include <math.h>

gboolean OnDraw(GtkWidget *w, GdkEvent *ev, gpointer data)
{
    GtkAllocation size;
    gtk_widget_get_allocation(w, &size);

    cairo_t *cr = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(w));
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 0, 0);
    cairo_arc(cr, size.width/2, size.height/2, size.height/2, 0, 2*M_PI);
    cairo_fill(cr);
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GdkNativeWindow nwnd = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    GtkWidget *plug = gtk_plug_new(nwnd);
    GtkWidget *canvas = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(plug), canvas);
    g_signal_connect(canvas, "expose-event", (GCallback)OnDraw, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(plug);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

The XID to be used is printed by the `server` and has to be copied/pasted as argument to the `client`:

```
$ ./server
60817441
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./server
$ bg
$ ./client 60817441
```

Comment: Rodrigo, this feels like it might be an answer, however, I'm such a newbie with GTK and Cairo, that I can't seem to put it all together looking at the documentation. Do you have a small code snippet that demonstrates what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @JimNorton - I've written a very simple example, I hope it may be enough to get you started.